# Get Quantity for each product using React Context

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, react-context

I have my state for the Cart.

```
  const [cart, setCart] = useState([]);
```

I have these functions in my context that adds and remove products respectively.

```
// Add Product to cart and save to current user {}
  const addProduct = (product) => {
    const exist = cart.find((x) => x.id === product.id);
    if (exist) {
      setCart(
        cart.map((x) =>
          // Expose quantity to any component from here...
          x.id === product.id ? { ...exist, qty: exist.qty + 1 } : x
        )
      );
      
    } else {
      setCart([...cart, { ...product, qty: 1 }]);
      
    }
  };

  const removeProduct = (product) => {
    const exist = cart.find((x) => x.id === product.id);
    if (exist.qty === 1) {
      setCart(cart.filter((x) => x.id !== product.id));
      
    } else {
      setCart(
        cart.map((x) =>
          // Expose quantity to any component from here...
          x.id === product.id ? { ...exist, qty: exist.qty - 1 } : x
        )
      );
    }
  };
```

The problem now is that I want to get the quantity for each product.

I loop my product like so: note: product is coming from a Firestore.

Shop Page.

```
{products?.map((docsSnapshot) => {
                const doc = docsSnapshot.data();
                const product = { ...doc, id: docsSnapshot.id };
                const inCart = Boolean(cart.find((el) => el.id === product.id));
                return (
                  <ProductList
                    key={docsSnapshot?.id}
                    docsSnapshot={docsSnapshot}
                    product={product}
                    onAddToCart={(product) => addProduct(product)}
                    onRemoveFromCart={(product) => removeProduct(product)}
                    inCart={inCart}
                  />
                );
              })}
```

Product List Page

```
<HStack justify={{ base: "center" }}>
              <IconButton
                size={"xs"}
                aria-label="Remove quantity"
                onClick={() => onRemoveFromCart(product)}
                icon={<RiSubtractLine size={"18px"} />}
              />
              <Text fontSize={"12px"}>{use Quantity here...}</Text>
              <IconButton
                size={"xs"}
                onClick={() => onAddToCart(product)}
                aria-label="Add Quantity"
                colorScheme={"success"}
                icon={<RiAddLine size={"18px"} />}
              />
            </HStack>
```

Product Details Page

```
<Text fontSize={"12px"}>{use quantity here too...}</Text>.
```

Lastly, I also want to check the cart has that product already.

Something like

```
const inCart = // Check if the item already exists in the cart's array
```

Comment: Just add one more function to your context fetching the value for the state

Comment: Please can you shed light on this

Comment: I have added a solution to it. Check if it helps!

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a cart context initial something like this

```
// In CartContext.js

const CartContext = React.createContext({
    items: [],
    addItem: (item) => {},
    deleteItem: (id) => {},
});

export default CartContext;
```

Then for your provider you can do something like below.

```
// In CartProvider.js
const CartProvider = (props) =>{ 

 const [cart, setCart] = useState([]);

... 
your add and remove functions for the product
...

const cartContext = {
        items: cart,
        
        addItem: addProduct,
        removeItem: removeProduct,
    };

    return (
        <CartContext.Provider value={cartContext}>
            {props.children}
        </CartContext.Provider>
    );
}
```

Then wrap the components inside which you want your cart value.

After which, Suppose you want to use the value in Shop page. Import the cartcontext and get a instance of it.

```
    const cartCtx = useContext(CartContext);
```

Now the context data should be available.

Now you can access the data normally like `cartCtx.items` and do whatever you like. For adding and removing try to pass the data using a reference function like (change the values accordingly based off of the data) this ( I have added for removing or deleting product, you can do similarly for adding product)

```
const handleItemDelete = (id) => {
        cartCtx.removeItem(productId);
    };


const cartItemsList = cartCtx.items.map((item) => {
        return (
            <CartItem
                key={item._id ?? item.id} 
                {...props}

                ...your custom fields

                {...item}
                handleItemDelete={handleItemDelete}
            />
        );
    });
...
```

Also, If you are doing more complicated operations like a e-commerce site, probably make use of useReducer or Redux toolkit (preferred, since I did notice some performance issues while I was doing the same with context but need to check further on this)